# Возможно ли средствами javascript прочитать сокеты по ip/порту стороннего сервера?

Tags: javascript, websocket

Сейчас с помощью php получаю данные из разных сокетов по ip:port (с помощью фунуции fsockopen). Это делается для получения играющей в данный момент композиции на разных радиостанциях:

```
$open = fsockopen($radioip,$radioport,$errno,$errstr,'.5');
    if ($open) {
        fputs($open,"GET /7.html HTTP/1.1\nUser-Agent:Mozilla\n\n");
        stream_set_timeout($open,'1');
        $read = fread($open,255); }
```

В результате основной javascript на главной странице регулярно обращается к этому php на сервере.
Хочется, чтобы всё это работало без лишних запросов к серверу, а средствами самого браузера. Возможно ли сделать подобную функцию на javascript - чтобы передавать ей ip и port а в результате получать необходимые данные?

Comment: Не путайте сокеты и вебсокеты. Подключиться из браузера к произвольному порту по сокетам невозможно в принципе и в ближайшие несколько лет вряд ли будет возможно. Смиритесь с этим и ищите обходные пути для решения вашей задачи (например, делайте всю работу на сервере через этот самый php — ну то есть как вы сейчас и делаете).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К сожалению, любые запросы браузером вне вашего "Origin" возможны только, если на той отвечающей стороне в заголовках ответов есть Access-Control-Allow-Origin с вашим origin. Это дело все закрыто для безопастности, т.к. если бы можно было с любого сайта вызывать AJAXом другой - очень много всего плохого можно было бы делать так.

Подробнее про кросс-доменный AJAX например [вот тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain)

Websockets при этом вам в данном случае совершенно не помогут, т.к. это отдельный протокол обмена данными между сервером и клиентом. И причем последнее время браузеры все чаще форсируют wss (шифрованные вебсокеты), для которых помимо поддержки Websockets еще и SSL на этом поддерживающем сервере нужен. Так что вам особо без промежуточного php скрипта не обойтись.

Если вы задаетесь этим вопросом по причине большой нагрузки на ваш сервер - стоит задуматься облегчением этого всего дела чем-то типа тех же websockets. Только не сторонними серверами, а вашим собственным. Который будет например сам с какой-то определенной частотой обновлять свой кэш по удаленным серверам и с определенной частотой(или по факту изменения) присылать информацию клиентам. В websockets соединение держится и в нем возможен двухсторонний диалог между клиентом и сервером. Тем самым клиентам не нужно будет постоянно обращаться к какой-либо страничке, а они просто получат websocket message по факту его отправки. Такое можно реализовать например на Node.js или ASP.net. На PHP лично я не видел подобных штук.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй веб сокеты HTML5.

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://IPAddress:PORT");
socket.onopen = function() {
  alert("Соединение установлено.");
};

socket.onclose = function(event) {
  if (event.wasClean) {
    alert('Соединение закрыто чисто');
  } else {
    alert('Обрыв соединения'); // например, "убит" процесс сервера
  }
  alert('Код: ' + event.code + ' причина: ' + event.reason);
};

socket.onmessage = function(event) {
  alert("Получены данные " + event.data);
};

socket.onerror = function(error) {
  alert("Ошибка " + error.message);
};
```

Comment: Попробовал, поочередно выдаёт: Ошибка undefined / Обрыв соединения / Код: 1006 причина: ... Вот например с этим радио: 93.100.61.75:8000.

Comment: А как сделать GET запрос, аналогичном тому что у меня используется в php: `fputs($open,"GET /7.html HTTP/1.1\nUser-Agent:Mozilla\n\n");` ?

Comment: @federk, никак, если на целевом сервере не поддерживаются/нет обрабатывающего кода для вебсокетов

Comment: @Grundy, а как у вебсокетов с CORS?

Comment: @Qwertiy, если не ошибаюсь там все в первый запрос на установку соединения упирает - он же идет обычным get или чего-то там и для него как раз нужно все по стандарту заголовки и т.д.

Comment: @Grundy Ну вот код на php, что в теме указан, успешно срабатывает и возвращает необходимую строку. Это же значит на целевом сервере есть обработчик для вебсокетов. Мне бы просто аналог на javascript для этой цели...

Comment: на самом деле нет. Это не значит, что _на целевом сервере **есть обработчик для вебсокетов**_

Comment: @federk, на самом деле нет. Это не значит, что _на целевом сервере **есть обработчик для вебсокетов**_

Comment: @Grundy А почему тогда php успешно открывает соединение и получает данные через функцию сокета по этому ip:port?

Comment: @federk, потому что пхп при этом не использует **web**сокеты

Answer (score 1):

1006    CLOSE_ABNORMAL  Reserved. Used to indicate that a connection was closed abnormally (that is, with no close frame being sent) when a status code is expected.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CloseEvent

Из мозиловского справочника по CloseEvent
Но я предполагаю, что на той стороне просто не websocket server, а если это так, то со страницы (читай из браузера) вы никак не получите поток данных с этого сокета.

Comment: А почему тогда у php получается получить данные из этого сокета без ошибок? Да, и я до этого не проверял - по http можно увидеть необходимые данные - http://93.100.61.75:8000/7.html. Если не через сокет, то можно ли как-нибудь средствами браузера прочитать эти данные со стороннего сервера?

Comment: var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', ' http://93.100.61.75:8000/7.html');
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
  alert(client.responseText);
}
client.send();

Comment: Такой код не работает.

Comment: Дико извиняюсь вот верный вариант
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); xhr.open('GET', ' http://93.100.61.75:8000/7.html', false); xhr.send(); if (xhr.status != 200) {alert( xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText ); } else { alert( xhr.responseText ); }

Comment: VM872:7 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://93.100.61.75:8000/7.html. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Но там другая проблема(((( Не хотят они чтоб кто то это читал

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы вы могли подключиться по WebSocket к тому серверу, тот сервер должен поддерживать [протокол WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#Protocol_handshake), который несколько отличается от HTTP.

Для всех популярных серверов есть модули для поддержки этого протокола.

Если же вы не контролируете удаленный сервер, то остается посоветовать кешировать данные: например, если вы знаете что сейчас играет такая-то секунда `t` композиции длительностью `s`, то в следующий раз обратиться к тому серверу вам нужно лишь через `s-t` секунд.

За исключением технологии WebSocket и очевидных дыр в браузерах, [вы не можете](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) подсоединяться для получения данных используя только JS к произвольным портам на произвольных IP. Представьте себе если бы это было возможно!

Comment: То есть ответ на мой вопрос - можно? ("за исключением" в вашем ответе). Почему тогда работает код на php, что я указал в вопросе, а javascript аналогичным образом не хочет работать? С конкретно вот этим примером: 93.100.61.75:8000 (да и любым другим ShoutCast радио)

Comment: Потому что код PHP выполняется у вас на сервере, а код JS - на главной странице в браузере. Оттуда все ограничения браузеров. Если вы будете выполнять код JS на стороне сервера, то таких ограничений не будет.